# smart tv channel display

Tags: javascript, html, platform, television

I need to make application on samsung smart tv using javascript, html and css.
The main task is display broadcasing channels and control it. 
These task was not difficult with LG smart TV implementing:

```
<object id="broadcast" type="application/x-netcast-broadcast" width=240 height=180></object>
```

But is samsung smart tv has the same solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use web device API `<script src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/webapi/1.0/webapis"></script>` and then you can get access to webapis object.

For more info look here: http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/ref00011/deviceapi_tv.html